# python's shlex.split alternative for Go

Tags: shell, parsing, go, quotes

Simple question - is there something like python's shlex.split that would allow me to simply parse/split/quote/escape shell-like quoted/backslashed strings ?

Link to shlex docs:
http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html

Example of what shlex.split does:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('abc ab\\ c  "ab\\"cd" key="\\"val\\""')
['abc', 'ab c', 'ab"cd', 'key="val"']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing in the standard library, but Google did publish their own [shlex](https://github.com/google/shlex) library which has been forked and changed some in [flynn-archive/go-shlex](https://github.com/flynn-archive/go-shlex).

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/shlex"
)

func main() {
    input := "abc ab\\ c  \"ab\\\"cd\" key=\"\\\"val\\\"\""
    fmt.Println("Processing:", input)
    tokens, _ := shlex.Split(input)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", tokens)
    // []string{"abc", "ab c", "ab\"cd", "key=\"val\""}
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/shlex is archived and not sure if there is an replacement for it.

Comment: <strike>You might prefer https://pkg.go.dev/mvdan.cc/sh/v3@v3.6.0/shell</strike> These functions do a lot more: path/envvar expansion, for example, so aren't a direct replacement.

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about the repo being archived. It's archived because they're not going to improve it. It's still available because it works.